# What css styling should I apply in order to get same effect as mac's sound popup as attached

Tags: html, css, styling

If you notice it is affected by background image and gives pretty shining translucent color effect when background is colorful. I tried with rgba(255,0,0,0.3)  but it gives transparent effect I rather want translucent effect (Please Ignore Icons in modal, I just want the background effect)!!

PFA[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best name for the effect that you want is called "blur"; hopefully that's enough to search around on Google if you need more.

The CSS property to achieve this effect is the [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter). Unfortunately, it has not been standardized yet.

If you don't want to wait, the only real way to achieve this is with HTML5 Canvas. [See here](http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript) for an implementation.

Comment: This helps. Thanks.